# Method to support integer input with replace and Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field which I only want positive and negative integers to be allowed in. I track their typing with onkeyup() since that's the most consistent across browsers. The real issue comes in when trying to replace non-numeric characters without replacing the dash at the start.

```
if(e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) {
    var data = e.target.value;

    if(e.target.value.match(/^[-]?/))
        e.target.value = '-' + data.substr(1).replace(/\D*/, "");
    else
        e.target.value = data.replace(/\D*/,"");
    }
```

Basically what's happening here is I ignore when they type in numbers, but for everything else attempt to replace anything they may have added that isn't a number. The issue with this right now is when I press Backspace, the dash comes back right away for some reason.

E.g. 
My input field has this: - 
 When I press backspace. 
My input field stays as this: -

WORKING CODE:

```
        if(e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) {
            var data = e.target.value;

            if(e.target.value.match(/^[-]+/))
                e.target.value = '-' + data.substr(1).replace(/\D/, "");
            else { console.log('else');
                e.target.value = data.replace(/\D/,"");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the issue, Renegade has a decent method, but I made a Regex mistake. It should be this:

```
if(e.target.value.match(/^[-]+/))
```

Rather than:

```
if(e.target.value.match(/^[-]?/))
```

Since the latter will give true even if the dash does not exist. ? means 0 or 1 matches, + is 1 or more.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) {
```

to

```
if((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) && e.keyCode!=8) {
```

Then you'll ignore the backspace character just like a number, which won't cause any other issues.